# Bootstrap SB Admin 2 Theme customization

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

I am using SB Admin 2 in my project.

My problem is all the default elements are bit large for my project. All the navbar, buttons, tables and so on. If i zoomed the browser to 80%, it looks really well for me.

So I added zoom : 80% to the wrapper div. It look and work well with Chrome browser but with Firefox.

I tried the transform in Firefox. It does not give the elements zoom effect but a zoom for whole page, which leaves an empty border in the screen.

```
.zoom_div{
  zoom: 80%;
  -moz-transform:  scale(0.8);

}
```

So what can I do for this?

Answer (score 0):

According to [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/?search=zoom), `zoom` is not supported by Firefox.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom) :

> Non-standard: This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards
> track.
>
> [...]
>
> transform: scale() should be used
> instead of this property, if possible. However, unlike CSS Transforms,
> zoom affects the layout size of the element.

Comment: I tried the transform in Firefox. It does not give the elements zoom effect but a zoom for whole page, which leaves an empty border in the screen.

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve your problem, I just gave the information why `zoom` isn't working on Firefox. I suggest you to add a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so people will help you more easily

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added a code block